# Record constructor is not called when copying with "with" operator

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var foo = new Foo("a");
var boo = foo with { Test = "b" };

public record Foo
{
    public Foo(string test)
    {
        Test = test;
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
    }
    
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

When I run it, the "TEST" string is being written once to the console. I suppose this is as expected, but what I am wondering is how is the new instance of a record created without calling the only constructor avaialable?

Perhaps record is generating another copy constructor behind the scenes that is not available for a direct usage or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps record is generating another copy constructor behind the scenes that is not available for a direct usage or something like that.

Yes, this is exactly what happens, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation):

> To implement [`with` expressions] for record class types, the compiler synthesizes a clone method and a copy constructor. The virtual clone method returns a new record initialized by the copy constructor. When you use a with expression, the compiler creates code that calls the clone method and then sets the properties that are specified in the with expression.

An example of the generated code can be seen using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTADAsAUOCMtYgMwAIBOBTAxgewwBM0AxPPWAb1jVrVVPIAoR4I0AXLAZw4EoadajDqi0AFR4c0AXk5SA3ILH14ATiYAicQFEAyuM18lIugF9laSw1btJvNJTQBzLBwVpubjxZhmgA===):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
public virtual Foo <Clone>$()
{
    return new Foo(this);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
protected Foo(Foo original)
{
    <Test>k__BackingField = original.<Test>k__BackingField;
}
```

You can declare your own copy constructor, if you want it to do something custom when using `with`:

```
protected Foo(Foo other) {
    Test = other.Test;
    Console.WriteLine("TEST");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does a *lot* when you use `record`; you can see this [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQhAbgIZQAEAZhBBQLwUB2MA7hQGK0AUARKbwCUAbhLkKwWg2pTWASwAuACwoBvCgBUYAZwXTewXhQC+oogQwBmCrEhQAJp1qFVhCu4pWnEbhhwAGCgUdBUE3D1cCD2jNEOlg3TMYjz8ATj4NAFEAZQ0hJI9jcPdiz2s/QK1dNQoAcxgFYQptBqaigmMgA===) - but short version: this uses an unpronounceable `<Clone>$` method, and a constructor *you can't see*:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
public virtual Foo <Clone>$()
{
    return new Foo(this);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
protected Foo(Foo original)
{
    <Test>k__BackingField = original.<Test>k__BackingField;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[SharpLab to the rescue](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQAbgIZQAEAZhBOQLzkB2MA7uQGI0AUARCTwEoA3IVIVgNelUksAlgBcAFuQDe5ACowAzvKk9gPcgF8RBQhgDM5WJCgATDjUIrC5N+UuOIXDDgAM5PLa8gKu7i4E7lEawVJBOqbR7r4AnLzqAKIAyuqCie5GYW5FHla+AZo6quQA5jDyQuRa9Y2FBEZAA).

There is a compiler-generated clone method and copy constructor:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
public virtual Foo <Clone>$()
{
    return new Foo(this);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
protected Foo(Foo original)
{
    <Test>k__BackingField = original.<Test>k__BackingField;
}
```

(Having both matters when you're dealing with inheritance).

The wither then compiles to:

```
var foo = new Foo("a")
var bar = foo.<Clone>$();
bar.Test = "b";
```

If you use init-only properties, or primary constructors (which generate init-only properties), then the compiler is allowed to generate code which assigns to those after calling the clone method, even though it prevents you from doing the same in code which you write.